# Error: Too many positional arguments: sites tmp FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins stage here which tires to ssh and execute a command.

```
stage("example"){
script{

sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${WPENGINE_ENV}@${WPENGINE_ENV}.${DOCKER_NODE} wp db query \"SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE ${topic_name}\""
}

}
```

Im getting the below error

```
+ ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no bts@btse.ssh.wpengi.net wp db query SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'bt_topic%'
Warning: Permanently added '' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Error: Too many positional arguments: sites tmp FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE bt_topic%
```

It's due to the '"'. The Jenkins is not accepting the " before the select statement. Can someone help.

Comment: Your quoting is weird. The first quoted string starts at _ssh_  and runs up to _db query_, then comes an unquoted part starting with _SELECT_ and ending with {topic_name}, and finally you have an empty string (`""`). The bizarre quoting is also obvious if you look at the syntax highlighting done by stackoverflow on your command.

Comment: How can we quote that. The command should be wp db query "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'topic_name5' "@user1934428

Comment: Sorry, forget my comment about the quoting. I missed that you used the backslash correctly. I think I found the real error and will try an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm neither proficient in `Groovy` nor `wp`, I'll try an answer:

The *sites tmp* in the error message tells us, that the `*` is interpreted by the shell, causing filename generation to be performed. In fact, your `sh` command is creating a command of the form

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no XXX@YYY.ZZZ wp db query "SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE TTTT"
```

(with appropriate values for XXX, YYY etc. being filled in from your variables). This in turn means that, after the shell has eaten the quotes in this command, ssh sees as positional parameters (i.e. after the options) the following values:

arg1: XXX@YYY.ZZZ
arg2: wp
arg3: db
arg4: query
arg5: SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE TTTT

ssh now invokes on the remote host (arg1) a shell and passes to it the command

```
wp db query SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE TTTT
```

You can see that the shell is asked to filename-expand the '*'. This is not good.

I do not know the `wp db query` command, but assuming that after `query`, a **single** paremeter should represent the query, the command being executed should instead look like

```
wp db query 'SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE TTTT'
```

We therefore need to provide single quotes for ensuring, that the the remote shell is seeing only one argument after the query, and also does not do any funny expansion on its own. This can be done by

```
sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${WPENGINE_ENV}@${WPENGINE_ENV}.${DOCKER_NODE} wp db query \"'SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE ${topic_name}'\""
```

**UPDATE** (based on the comment of the OP):

If `topic_name` itself contains single quotes which need to be conserved as part of the query, you have two possibilities:

1. Modify the variable `topic_name`, so that each `'` is represented as `\'`
2. ONLY IF `topic_name` is guaranteed to contain a double quote: Write the command as

   sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${WPENGINE_ENV}@${WPENGINE_ENV}.${DOCKER_NODE} wp db query "'SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE '${topic_name}""

WARNING: In both cases, ensure that `topic_name` does not contain a backslash. If it does, you have to escape this too.

Comment: + ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no btste@bts.ssh.wpgine.net wp db query 'SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'bt_topic%''
Warning: Permanently added 'bage.ssh.wpene.net,3.10.65.183' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Error: Too many positional arguments: sites tmp FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE bt_topic%

Comment: It seems that your variable `topic_name` contains a single quote. Please check, whether this is the case.

Comment: yeah it need single quotes

Comment: Then one possibility is to escape the single quotes inside topic_name (`\'). With this type of questions, it would always be helpful (also for your own debugging) if you write down exactly what parameters the program you are running is supposed to see (similar to what  I have done when showing, what arguments `ssh` gets).  Another possibility is to use the fact that in shell, string catenation is simply done by writing the strings adjent to each other.

Comment: @JUSTINEMATHEW : I have updated my response based on your comment. But honestly speaking, this kind of quoting/escaping hell can get your head spinning. If I would write such a command, I would appoach it in a different way: To get the shell interpretation out of my way as much as possible, I would store the whole string for the query (i.e. the whole `SELECT` statement) into an environment variable and have `ssh` transport this variable via `~/.ssh/environment` to the host. In addition, I would run the command on the host via `zsh`, not bash, so that I don't even have to use double quotes.